# Helical cross-section as result of lathe/milling operation (cylinder intersection)

Tags: solid-geometry

I suspect a simple wooden toy "lead screw" was made by advancing a cylindrical rotary cutting tool ( *Cylindrical End Mill Cutter*) along the surface of the rotating wooden dowel (base cylinder), resulting in a helical cut (the axes of the cylinders are orthogonal (*skew*).

[image]

Videos of the manufacturing process close to what I suspect:

- https://youtu.be/5U9lJAgU1oE?t=31 (but: spherical cutter. radial, not tangent end mill)
- https://youtu.be/y5DOQWiexOQ?t=314 (cutter radial)
- https://youtu.be/pbaRRsG3BN4?t=9 (not radial, but "tilted")

I have tried to visualise/emulate the resulting geometry using multiple `difference` operations for cylinder primitives in [(Open)JSCAD](https://openjscad.org/) (see code at end of post) and adjusted the view manually:

[image: image of helical track approximated by multiple cylinder (*End mill*)-cuts]

What is the equivalent (elliptical?) shape that is the cross-section of the helical path?

---

And: what is the contact surface/line/point of another, slightly smaller cylinder that is used as "lead screw nut" (having the same orientation as the cutting cylinder, i.e. orthogonal to the base cylinder) - a point contact on one of the helical edges?

Code for JSCAD

```
function main () {
    let main = cylinder({r: 3, h:10, center: true, fn: 64 });
    for (let i=0; i<36; i++)    {
        let cut = cylinder({r: 0.2, h:10, center: true});
        cut = translate([0,-3,0],cut);
        cut = rotate([0,90,i*3],cut);
        cut = translate([0,0,i*0.1],cut);
        main = difference(main, cut);
    }
    return main;
}
```

<s>I think the underlying question may be about the surface created by a straight line moved along a spiral ( or helix):</s>

[image: blender screenshot]
(created with Blender: a mesh edge with Screw modifier)

Or the surface created by a helix that has been rotated (spin):

[image]

The cross-section of the "cutting" cylinder (*End mill*) is a circle of course, <s>which is what an infinite number of cuts "converge" to (a cylinder with zero length).</s>

Then the cross-section along the helix should be an ellipse (intersection of the hypothetical "cutting" cylinder (*End mill cutter*) and the plane orthogonal to the helix).

---

It's not the same as moving a circle along the helix; to illustrate, I've reduced the cylinder's length:
[image]

My "straight line" theory does not apply either, I think these "lines" might be helices created by the intersection of the translated and rotated "cutting" cylinders.

So it seems this might be much more involved than I anticipated -- please don't spend too much time on this on my account. I was just curious to see whether the "cut" could be better created in 3D by "lofting" the equivalent cross-section along a helix.

Comment: Feel free to edit/correct for proper terminology...

Comment: Let me try to understand. A rotating milling cutter offset and skewed with respect to axis of  the vertical wooden cylinder shown is mounted on a stationary tool post, when it mills out a one-sheeted hyperboloid of revolution. If the tool post moves additionally with a helical pitch $p$ around the vertical axis of cylinder, what is the parametrization of that ruled surface? Is that your question?

Comment: @ handle Please give some more explanation of the motion of milling cutter and its orientation, preferably and if possible using a video of  fabrication.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, thanks for your interest, I will upload an image to clarify, but it will take a few days.

Comment: @ handle: I have edited to include the *End Mill* as equivalent to the cylindrical cutter you mention. Please roll back if you feel the description is improper.

Comment: @Narasimham By all means, also feel free to include the proper mathematical/geometrical terms. I am aware of the shortcomings of my understanding and vocabulary... Meanwhile, when I can find some time, I am working out how to better visualise the question with Blender...

Comment: The videos give a better idea. Shall be back after a couple of days. Meanwhile..did you aim to cut a particular helical groove profile  into the leadscrew and so chose successive router cutting thicknesses to remove material? Or is there just a single profile required to result from a single router of the corresponding shape that moves lengthwise on the lathe ? If so please indicate the profile by a sketch.

Comment: @Narasimham No, I'm assuming a single cylindrical cutter whose axis is tangent to the base cylinder, removing a half-circle of material. It's a single profile. Please don't put much more effort into this on my account, it seems it's much more complicated than I anticipated. I thought there might be a simple relation between cylindrical cutter and equivalent cross-section on the helix/tangent (so as to be able to "loft" or "extrude" that cross-section along the helical path in order to create a better 3D model).

Comment: It is now quite clear  and I suppose it is not that complicated to model it..You can also  do *fluted millings* which can be for two, three or four (multiple) starts...( like multi-start screw threads.) The hollow profile itself is not so important as  is leading cutting helical edge..and the rake and relief angles provided around it.

Comment: Your videos are too varied. You should stay to the point.

Comment: From your first figure, I confirm my parametric model. You have an helix with circular vertical cross sections (that circle is the cross-section of the cutting tool). Oblique cross-sections are not ellipses.

Comment: @handle: I hope to soon add another answer or edit my present one in view of your videos, in order to include machine motions and generated geometrical shape formulation.

Comment: @ handle Semi-circular  cross section occurs only when the radial interference equals cutter radius.

Comment: We should thank the moderator in advance.. for not showing us the chat door. Your question combines math of geometry applied to commonly known conventional mechanical machining processes.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, the cutting surface is described by a revolving vertical circle, the center of which describes an helix of vertical axis.

Parametrically:

$$\begin{cases}x=(R+r\cos u)\cos\ t,\\y=(R+r\cos u)\sin t,\\z=r\sin u+a^2t.\end{cases}$$

At time $0$, the plane normal to the helix is normal to the tangent vector $(0,R,a)$ and  has the equation

$$Ry+az=0.$$

Hence the equation of the intersection of the cutting surface and the normal plane is given by the condition

$$R(R+r\cos u)\sin t+ar\sin u+a^2t=0.$$

This equation is transcendental in $t$, but can be solved for $u$.

$$(r\sin t)\cos u+(ar)\sin u=-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)$$

gives

$$r\sin u=\frac{-a(a^2t+R^2\sin t)\pm \sin t\sqrt{(r\sin t)^2+(ar)^2-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)^2}}{\sin^2t+a^2}$$

and $$r\cos u=\frac{-\sin t(a^2t+R^2\sin t)\mp a\sqrt{(r\sin t)^2+(ar)^2-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)^2}}{\sin^2t+a^2}.$$

Finally, the curve is given by the planar coordinates $\left(x,\dfrac{-ay+Rz}{\sqrt{a^2+R^2}}\right)$ obtained by rotating the coordinate frame. The final equation is terrible. It does not describe an ellipse.

$$\begin{cases}x=\left(R+\dfrac{-\sin t(a^2t+R^2\sin t)\mp a\sqrt{(r\sin t)^2+(ar)^2-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)^2}}{\sin^2t+a^2}\right)\cos t,
\\y'=\\\dfrac1{\sqrt{a^2+R^2}}\left(-a\left(R+\dfrac{-a(a^2t+R^2\sin t)\pm\sin t\sqrt{(r\sin t)^2+(ar)^2-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)^2}}{\sin^2t+a^2}\right)+R\left(\dfrac{-a(a^2t+R^2\sin t)\pm \sin t\sqrt{(r\sin t)^2+(ar)^2-(a^2t+R^2\sin t)^2}}{\sin^2t+a^2}+a^2t\right)\right).
\end{cases}$$

I leave the study of this curve to the future generations.

---

**Resolution of the trigonometric equation:**

$$a\cos u+b\sin u=c\implies a^2(1-\sin^2u)=c^2-2bc\sin u+b^2\sin^2u$$

gives

$$\sin u=\frac{bc\pm a\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{a^2+b^2}$$

and by symmetry

$$\cos u=\frac{ac\mp b\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{a^2+b^2}.$$

---

Disclaimer: done by hand, typos are not excluded.

Comment: Thanks - would this be equivalent to Narasimham's "simple twisted tube" (can you recommend an online plotting tool that accepts the parameter equations?)? I think that it might not be the actual shape (see updated post).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand the motions. At first I imagined that you were referring to a simple twisted tube of $(x,y,z)$ parametrization:

[image: Tube here]

however no clue about where the straight straight line generators come from. So this is discarded. What appears to me is that a rotating milling cutter offset distance $b$ normally from cylinder axis and skewed angle $\alpha$ with respect to axis of the vertical wooden cylinder. It is mounted on a stationary tool post and mills out a one-sheeted Hyperboloid of revolution. If the tool post in addition moves with a helical pitch $ p= c\, \theta$ is the added torsion component around the vertical axis of cylinder. Required is a parametrization of the generated ruled surface.

*Hyperboloid of one sheet* is seen in parametrization when $c=0.$ When $z$ motion is imparted to the rotating milling cutter we are adding as pitch $p= 2 \pi c $ for each turn of the lathe.

$$r(u)= \sqrt{(u \cos \alpha)^2+b^2}$$

$$ (x,y,z)=(r(u) \cos \theta,r(u) \sin \theta,u \sin \alpha + c\, \theta). $$

EDIT1;

[image]

(In view of clarification)..The following surface is a helical channel groove made by a standard end-mill or router that can be CNC programmed:

[image: Helical Channel CNC]

Comment: Where would an hyperboloid come from ? In the case of $c=0$, you get a torus, and a slanted cross section is a quartic curve.

Comment: 1) We can see in the first figure straight line generators left behind after milling cuts are made in the wooden cylinder. 2) Also in the Blender output  locus of straight lines tangential to helix are well known lines of stiction defining a developable helicoid ruled surface.3) Let us wait and hear more clarifying comments from the OP.

Comment: IMO, they aren't straight. They are cut by a circular tool. The surface is a "spring", i.e. an helix with circular vertical cross sections. The oblique sections are ovals, pseudo-ellipses. But maybe I also misunderstand.

Comment: ( Figures 1 and 2). The straight line projections clearly belong to straight lines in 3D. Time being we await a reply from OP?

Answer (score 0):

With videos the question is more clear. We can consider the simplest router section to be a rectangular groove like a channel in a flat plate.

When wrapped around a cylinder isometrically we have a helical strip as channel bottom flanked by two developable helicoids on either side.

The cross section in general can be chosen arbitrary to suit any router shape that removes (wood) material by radial plunge and helical motion driven by lead screw.

The groove widths are $( w/\cos \alpha,w/\sin\alpha)$ along (circumferential,axial ) directions respectively.

If instead of a square router a ball end mill diameter $ 2w$ is chosen then we have the same radial dimension of groove but ellipses of axial dimension major axes $( 2w/\cos \alpha, 2w/\sin\alpha)$.

[image]

( to be continued)